# Рендер картинки из json файла в react компоненте

Tags: reactjs, json

Есть следующий компонент:

```
import React from 'react';
import data from '../data/data.json';
import './Product.css';

function Product() {
        return (
            <div className='block'>
                {data.map((el) => {
                    return (
                        <div className='product' key={el.id}>
                            <img className='product__image' src={el.img}></img>
                            <h3 className='product__title'>{el.title}</h3>
                            <h3 className='product__price'>{el.price}</h3>
                            <button className='product__button'>В корзину</button>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
}

export default Product;
```

json файл:

```
[
    {"id":1,"title":"Гитара Yamaha", "price":"6500", "img":"./img/guitar-yamaha.jpg"},
    {"id":2,"title":"Гитара Fender", "price":"7300", "img":"./img/guitar-fender.jpg"},
    {"id":3,"title":"Скрипка Yamaha", "price":"16000", "img":"./img/yamaha-violence.jpg"},
    {"id":4,"title":"Скрипка Cervini", "price":"4200", "img":"./img/violence-cervini.jpg"},
    {"id":5,"title":"Саксофон Yamaha", "price":"45000", "img":"./img/saxophone-yamaha.jpg"},
    {"id":6,"title":"Барабаны Yamaha", "price":"30000", "img":"./img/drums-yamaha.jpg"}
]
```

Структура проекта выглядит так:
[image: Структура проекта выглядит так]

Все рендерится прекрасно кроме картинок, они почему то не отображаются, в чем причина?

Comment: А что вам говорит вкладка network в консоли разработчика?

Comment: Скорее всего 404 на изображениях. Так как они находятся в папке `src`, а не в папке `public`. У меня была такая ошибка, но потом решил просто переместить файлы из папки src в папку public

Comment: @SwaD вроде как ничего

Comment: @YuraLons ошибки ни какой нет, перенес изображения в public, ничего не поменялось

Comment: Как получилось решить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам следует перенести все изображения в папку 'public' и поправить пути до изображений. Ваш путь должен начинаться с `/` - это папка `public` и дальше путь до изображения относительно этой папки.